# Passing a property object to method expecting NSObject results in pointer error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method in a custom FileIO (Input/Output) class with this definition:

```
- (void)saveObject:(NSObject*)object;
```

I have another class named MyClass that has a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyDataClass* myData; // subclassed from NSObject
```

I try to call the method with the property:

```
[fileIO saveObject:self.myData];
```

For some reason, I get a semantic warning:

```
Incompatible pointer types sending 'MyDataClass *' to parameter of type 'NSObject *'
```

Comment: Show the `@interface` line for `MyDataClass`. Does it extend `NSObject` (or another class that does)?

Comment: @interface MyDataClass : NSObject <NSCoding>

Comment: That's strange. It should work as far as i can see. Try restarting Xcode. Sometimes it gets confused.

Comment: restarted and cleaned the project, still have the warning.  Strange.

Comment: Did you import the proper .h file in this .m file? Perhaps the .m has only seen a forward reference to `MyDataClass`.

Comment: That's it, thanks @rmaddy want to apply it to the answer?  I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `MyDataClass` does in fact extend `NSObject`, the issue may arise if this .m file does not import (directly or indirectly) the .h for `MyDataClass`. If all it has seen is a forward declaration (via `@class`), the compiler doesn't yet know that `MyDataClass` extends `NSObject`.

Import the .h for `MyDataClass` and it should solve the problem.